# Parsing out prices in a nested structure of markets and runners?

Tags: python, json, for-loop

I'm fairly new to programming, and am trying to get my head around parsing json. Specifically, I'm working with a string that describes football betting markets, and contains (amongst many others) a value for individual matches(marketId), child values for each possible result (home/away/draw)(selectionId), and further child values for the price that you can back/lay at(price).

I've run my code through json.loads, and I've got this to work with, which I have assigned to the variable "output".

```
[{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[{"marketId":"1.139185909","isMarketDataDelayed":true,"status":"OPEN","betDelay":0,"bspReconciled":false,"complete":true,"inplay":false,"numberOfWinners":1,"numberOfRunners":3,"numberOfActiveRunners":3,"lastMatchTime":"2018-02-12T10:56:09.726Z","totalMatched":645229.98,"totalAvailable":1039329.11,"crossMatching":true,"runnersVoidable":false,"version":2045792715,"runners":[{"selectionId":55190,"handicap":0.0,"status":"ACTIVE","lastPriceTraded":1.4,"totalMatched":0.0,"ex":{"availableToBack":[{"price":1.39,"size":56703.76}],"availableToLay":[{"price":1.4,"size":35537.54}],"tradedVolume":[]}},{"selectionId":1703,"handicap":0.0,"status":"ACTIVE","lastPriceTraded":11.0,"totalMatched":0.0,"ex":{"availableToBack":[{"price":10.5,"size":3592.64}],"availableToLay":[{"price":11.0,"size":5913.05}],"tradedVolume":[]}},{"selectionId":58805,"handicap":0.0,"status":"ACTIVE","lastPriceTraded":5.3,"totalMatched":0.0,"ex":{"availableToBack":[{"price":5.2,"size":9136.62}],"availableToLay":[{"price":5.3,"size":5361.48}],"tradedVolume":[]}}]},{"marketId":"1.139782182","isMarketDataDelayed":true,"status":"OPEN","betDelay":0,"bspReconciled":false,"complete":true,"inplay":false,"numberOfWinners":1,"numberOfRunners":3,"numberOfActiveRunners":3,"lastMatchTime":"2018-02-12T10:25:33.842Z","totalMatched":1715.46,"totalAvailable":39526.8,"crossMatching":true,"runnersVoidable":false,"version":2044817355,"runners":[{"selectionId":18567,"handicap":0.0,"status":"ACTIVE","lastPriceTraded":2.3,"totalMatched":0.0,"ex":{"availableToBack":[{"price":2.22,"size":148.27}],"availableToLay":[{"price":2.32,"size":10.1}],"tradedVolume":[]}},{"selectionId":62683,"handicap":0.0,"status":"ACTIVE","lastPriceTraded":3.85,"totalMatched":0.0,"ex":{"availableToBack":[{"price":3.8,"size":76.9}],"availableToLay":[{"price":3.9,"size":20.57}],"tradedVolume":[]}},{"selectionId":58805,"handicap":0.0,"status":"ACTIVE","lastPriceTraded":3.25,"totalMatched":0.0,"ex":{"availableToBack":[{"price":3.2,"size":21.19}],"availableToLay":[{"price":3.5,"size":85.41}],"tradedVolume":[]}}]}], "id":1}]
```

I'm trying to extract the value of 'marketId', followed by their corresponding child values of 'selectionId' and 'price', which should look like this:

> ```
> 1.139185909 (marketId 0)
> 55190       (selectionId 0 under the first market)
> 1.39        (selectionId 0's back price)
> 1.4         (selectionId 0's lay price)
> 1703        (selectionId 1 under the first market)
> 10.5        (selectionId 1's back price)
> 11          (selectionId 1's lay price)
> 58805       (selectionId 2 under the first market)
> 5.2         (selectionId 2's back price)
> 5.3         (selectionId 2's lay price)
> 1.139782182 (marketId 1)
> 18567       (selectionId 0 under the second market)
> 2.22        (selectionId 0's back price)
> 2.32        (selectionId 0's lay price)
> 62683       (selectionId 1 under the second market)
> cont...
> ```

I've used for loops to print these values:

```
for i in output[0]['result']:
    print(i.get('marketId'))
    for j in output[0]['result'][0]['runners']:
        print(j.get('selectionId'))
        for k in output[0]['result'][0]['runners'][0]['ex']['availableToBack']:
            print(k.get('price'))
            for l in output[0]['result'][0]['runners'][0]['ex']['availableToLay']:
                print(l.get('price'))
```

When I run it though, it returns:

> ```
> 1.139185909  
> 55190        
> 1.39         
> 1.4          
> 1703         
> 1.39         
> 1.4
> 58805
> 1.39
> 1.4
> 1.139782182
> 55190
> 1.39
> 1.4
> 1703
> 1.39
> 1.4
> 58805
> 1.39
> 1.4
> ```

The marketId values are OK here, but when I try to return other nested values, the program keeps returning the first set of values it comes across. I can't seem to find an answer anywhere - how can I get it to return the correct values?

Comment: *I've run my code through json.loads, and I've got this to work with*: now you just have Python data. You have lists and dictionaries. This isn't really a JSON question, this is just a Python datastructure handling question now.

Comment: Your value for `output` a JSON document, not the Python data structure, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indicing to the first element of each of your lists. Your `for` loops do give you access to the other objects each time, but your nested loop then ignores those elements.

When you use

```
for i in output[0]['result']:
```

`i` is bound to each element in the `'result'` list, one by one, and you print out the `marketId` value for those.

But your next loop, then *ignores* all but the first one of those dictionaries:

```
for j in output[0]['result'][0]['runners']:
```

Here, `output[0]['result'][0]` is the first object bound to `i` in the outer loop. So for each `i`, you ignore the object (apart from using the `'markedId'` key), and then only look at the runners for the first such object.

Use the `'runners'` key of `i` instead:

```
for i in output[0]['result']:
    print(i.get('marketId'))
    for j in i['runners']:  # i is the object from the outer loop
        print(j.get('selectionId'))
        # ...
```

`i` is first bound to `output[0]['result'][0]`, then to `output[0]['result'][1]`, etc., so `i['runners']` now follows along and lets you process the correct substructure.

Do so for each nesting level; `j` is another dictionary, so use `j['ex']['availableToBack']`, etc.

You don't need to nest your `for` loops for the `availableToBack` and `availableToLay` entries either, `ex` contains just one dictionary object, and it has those two keys (which reference lists). You don't need to produce output for all `availableToLay` prices for each price in `availableToBack`.

It's easier to see all this if you pretty-print the Python data structure:

```
>>> pprint(output)
[{'id': 1,
  'jsonrpc': '2.0',
  'result': [{'betDelay': 0,
              'bspReconciled': False,
              'complete': True,
              'crossMatching': True,
              'inplay': False,
              'isMarketDataDelayed': True,
              'lastMatchTime': '2018-02-12T10:56:09.726Z',
              'marketId': '1.139185909',
              'numberOfActiveRunners': 3,
              'numberOfRunners': 3,
              'numberOfWinners': 1,
              'runners': [{'ex': {'availableToBack': [{'price': 1.39,
                                                       'size': 56703.76}],
                                  'availableToLay': [{'price': 1.4,
                                                      'size': 35537.54}],
                                  'tradedVolume': []},
                           'handicap': 0.0,
                           'lastPriceTraded': 1.4,
                           'selectionId': 55190,
                           'status': 'ACTIVE',
                           'totalMatched': 0.0},
                          {'ex': {'availableToBack': [{'price': 10.5,
                                                       'size': 3592.64}],
                                  'availableToLay': [{'price': 11.0,
                                                      'size': 5913.05}],
                                  'tradedVolume': []},
                           'handicap': 0.0,
                           'lastPriceTraded': 11.0,
                           'selectionId': 1703,
                           'status': 'ACTIVE',
                           'totalMatched': 0.0},
                          {'ex': {'availableToBack': [{'price': 5.2,
                                                       'size': 9136.62}],
                                  'availableToLay': [{'price': 5.3,
                                                      'size': 5361.48}],
                                  'tradedVolume': []},
                           'handicap': 0.0,
                           'lastPriceTraded': 5.3,
                           'selectionId': 58805,
                           'status': 'ACTIVE',
                           'totalMatched': 0.0}],
              'runnersVoidable': False,
              'status': 'OPEN',
              'totalAvailable': 1039329.11,
              'totalMatched': 645229.98,
              'version': 2045792715},
             {'betDelay': 0,
              'bspReconciled': False,
              'complete': True,
              'crossMatching': True,
              'inplay': False,
              'isMarketDataDelayed': True,
              'lastMatchTime': '2018-02-12T10:25:33.842Z',
              'marketId': '1.139782182',
              'numberOfActiveRunners': 3,
              'numberOfRunners': 3,
              'numberOfWinners': 1,
              'runners': [{'ex': {'availableToBack': [{'price': 2.22,
                                                       'size': 148.27}],
                                  'availableToLay': [{'price': 2.32,
                                                      'size': 10.1}],
                                  'tradedVolume': []},
                           'handicap': 0.0,
                           'lastPriceTraded': 2.3,
                           'selectionId': 18567,
                           'status': 'ACTIVE',
                           'totalMatched': 0.0},
                          {'ex': {'availableToBack': [{'price': 3.8,
                                                       'size': 76.9}],
                                  'availableToLay': [{'price': 3.9,
                                                      'size': 20.57}],
                                  'tradedVolume': []},
                           'handicap': 0.0,
                           'lastPriceTraded': 3.85,
                           'selectionId': 62683,
                           'status': 'ACTIVE',
                           'totalMatched': 0.0},
                          {'ex': {'availableToBack': [{'price': 3.2,
                                                       'size': 21.19}],
                                  'availableToLay': [{'price': 3.5,
                                                      'size': 85.41}],
                                  'tradedVolume': []},
                           'handicap': 0.0,
                           'lastPriceTraded': 3.25,
                           'selectionId': 58805,
                           'status': 'ACTIVE',
                           'totalMatched': 0.0}],
              'runnersVoidable': False,
              'status': 'OPEN',
              'totalAvailable': 39526.8,
              'totalMatched': 1715.46,
              'version': 2044817355}]}]
```

Your code would be more readable if you used more descriptive names:

```
for response in output:  # loop over the JSONRPC responses
    for market in response['result']:   # each is a market
        print(market['marketId'])
        for runner in market['runners']:
            print(runner['selectionId'])
            for entry in runner['ex']['availableToBack']:
                print(entry['price'])
            for entry in runner['ex']['availableToLay']:
                print(entry['price'])
```

This outputs:

```
1.139185909
55190
1.39
1.4
1703
10.5
11.0
58805
5.2
5.3
1.139782182
18567
2.22
2.32
62683
3.8
3.9
58805
3.2
3.5
```